# Query database for records with non-accented letters

Tags: sql, html, sqlite, web-sql, intel-xdk

I have a field in my database containing text like "Lobo de río" (note the accent on the letter "í".  I need to search this column for records `like '%rio%'`, where there is **no** accent on the "í".  I have tried several things but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for all values that only have non-extended ascii characters (the first 128).

```
select *
from yourTable
where yourColumn REGEXP '[\x00-\x7F]*';
```